# Why does nested for-next loops give weird results

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm confused of my nested for-next loops results.My Question is how does the computer read this function and come up with this result. I understand it reads up to down, but that would give me a result of 1,4,2,3,3,2,1. My result is wrong and I don't understand how the computer gets the real result.

When you have: 
    for outsideloop = 1, 3, 1 do
    print (outsideloop)
    end

It prints out 1,2,3

When you have:
    for insideloop = 4, 1, -1 do -- inside loop
    print (insideloop)
    end

Now when you have the insideloop nested inside the outside loop you get:

```
for outsideloop = 1, 3, 1 do -- outside loop

print (outsideloop)

for insideloop = 4, 1, -1 do -- inside loop

    print (insideloop)
end
end
```

with a result of 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1

This last result is my confusion. Can someone clear up my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a modified version of your program that might clarify what's going on. I've modified your program so the numbers printed by the inner loop are indented.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

for outsideloop = 1, 3, 1 do -- outside loop
    print (outsideloop)
    for insideloop = 4, 1, -1 do -- inside loop
        print ("", insideloop)
    end end
```

The output is:

```
1
        4
        3
        2
        1
2
        4
        3
        2
        1
3
        4
        3
        2
        1
```

The numbers printed by the outer loop are `1`, `2`, and `3`, in that order.

The numbers printed by the inner loop are `4`, `3`, `2`, and `1`, in that order -- and the inner loop is executed 3 times, once for each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

The output is correct.

1. outsideloop starts its first iteration with a value of 1
2. outsideloop is printed, hence printing 1
3. First iteration of insideloop starts, which gives 4
4. insideloop is printed, hence printing 4
5. Second iteration of insideloop starts, which is 3
6. insideloop is printed, hence printing 3
7. and insideloop continues printing 2 and 1
8. Second iteration of outsideloop starts at 2
9. outsideloop is printed, hence printing 2
10. insideloop runs again, printing 4 all the way down to 1(steps 3 to 7)
11. Third iteration of outsideloop starts
12. outsideloop is printed, hence printing 3
13. insideloop runs once more

Hope I could help!